# Tool for managing large numbers of SSL certificates

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, backup

My organisation has a lot of SSL certificates and managing them is a pain: we need to keep backups of private keys and certificates, keep them secure, deal with certificate renewals (we use different CAs, some of which require a new CSR each time) and occasionally generating new keys, either because we add a new server or because we need to increase the key size.

I suppose it would be possible to write a tool to automate all of the above, but before we commit to doing so, can anyone recommend a tool that does this already? Ideally it'd run on Linux via a command line or web interface.

Comment: You might get much better answers on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

I only know of tools that exist for the entire life cycle of a CA for example Windows Certification Services.

If however you are using a third party CA and simply want to keep good record from Linux, I would highly recommend you simply organise your current system.

When working with certificates I do something along the following:

Folder called `CSR` - keeps the requests
Folder called `Public` - keeps the public keys
Folder called `Private` - Keeps the private keys

all files called `xxxxxx.crt` / `xxxxxx.pem` etc, where x is the next available number - keep them the same so `000001.crt` is the public certificate to `000001.pem`'s private key.

Keep an up to date spreadsheet / database in the root folder that simply has the number in one column and details, expiry and any other relevant information in the next.

For a spreadsheet, this shouldn't take more than a few minutes to set up, but If you were to use a small database, you can probably build a little (but nice) DB in less than an hour that can do nice reports such as expiry warnings etc.

I think that this system could work out well for you.

Answer (score 2):

With no other tool than google, here are some possibilities:

[Venafi Digital Certificate Management & Encryption Key Management](http://www.venafi.com/)
[Trustwave Certificate Lifecycle Manager](https://ssl.trustwave.com/solutions-clm.php)

Both these products handle discovery, analysis, alerting and management.